How fast does a quantum torpedo leave the firing ship's launch tube?
A photon torpedo leaves the firing ship's launch tube at Warp 8. How fast does a quantum torpedo leave the firing ship's launch tube?

If it's really quantum then if you know it's leaving the tube, you don't know how fast it's going, right?

Correct, I have found definitions of how the yields are achieved (vacuum energy/weaponized ZPM). Also, I will accept that Warp 8 might be the maximum velocity that the ship launcher is capable of imparting. Also, they don't have to be faster, just have higher yields

@DavidW given that it goes slowly enough that the audience can easily track it with their eyes as long as the dramatic tension of the moment requires, the uncertainty seems to be translated into the chance of missing the target or (for Voyager) being regenerated an arbitrary number of times.  (Let's not talk about shuttlecraft.)

@DavidW We could use the Heisenberg compensators from the transporter system. Could also make for some interesting plot-points reliability-engineering wise.

"A photon torpedo leaves the firing ship's launch tube at Warp 8" — really? I'd expect them to hit their targets a lot quicker if they were travelling at Warp 8.

at the speed of the plot?

Warp 8 is what the Star Fleet tech manual/canon says. not what it looks like on the screen. I know resolving what you see with what the tech manual says is a problem.

Like Schrödinger's Cat out of a bag

I'm not sure what specific tech manual you're referring to, but to cover bases: While the TNG, DS9, and unpublished VOY tech manuals were based on Rick Sternbach's personal notes and used during screenwriting, they aren't technically canon (though they're awfully close to it). Franz Joseph's Star Trek Star Fleet Technical Manual was unofficial and unlicensed, as was Mr. Scott's Guide to the Enterprise by Shane Johnson. I'm not aware of any other Trek tech manuals that were ever published, so anything else would probably be an unpublished fan work.

From the TNG Technical manual on photon torpedos which are similar to quantum torpedos.
I read it as the sustainer field makes the torpedo slightly faster than the ship's warp field regardless of the ship's speed.

"The multimode sustainer engine is not a true warp engine
due to its small physical size, one-twelfth the minimum matter/
antimatter (M/A) reaction chamber size. Rather, it is a miniature M/A fuel cell, which powers the sustainer coils to grab
and hold a hand-off field from the launcher tube, to continue
at warp if launched during warp flight by the starship. The cell,
a cylinder 20 cm in diameter and 50 cm in length, is limited to
a narrow warp field frequency range and cannot add more
than a slight amount of power to the original hand-off field.
The maximum cruising velocity will follow the formula vmax= vf+0.75V/C, where v, is the launch velocity. Other flight modes
are triggered according to initial launch conditions. If launched
during low-impulse flight, the coils will drive the torpedo up to
a 75% higher sublight velocity. If launched at high sublight,
the sustainer will not cross the threshold into warp, but will
continue to drive the torpedo at high relativistic velocities.


No, I don't know how you would put a warp field generator into a photon/quantum torpedo case along with everything else you need to make it go 'boom' to sustain that warp 8 speed, but that is what the Canon tech manuals say.

@CarlNelson: Sounds like the quote says it doesn't have a warp field generator. Just a much simpler mechanism that sustains an existing warp bubble "borrowed" from the launching ship. In short, wibbly-wobbly, spacey-wacey.

OK, maybe it is not canon & just fan base stuff. I am not trying to start an argument, as I have not read every single one of the numerous 'tech' manuals out there. I have seen that number posted on several internet sites. I am willing to accept Warp 8 as a definitive speed and go on from there. If anyone thinks Warp 8 is too fast or not sustainable that is alright with me. I am just a fan and a writer who wants a plausible speed that could work, & if I use something like it in one of my stories, I would try to come up with a logical explanation as to how why it works that way.

Also if you are a writer and you use something like this in your writing and it works for you, if it doesn't work for you as a writer then use something else. Science fiction writers have been coming up with tropes to move their stories along for decades and as long as I can see the logic within their stories I am fine with that since we are not talking about real science, but something that someone wrote to make their story work, hence internal logic.

Carl I have a suspicion Trek tech manuals became sketchy nonsense in the First Contact era from what little I've seen of the Sovereign class tech writing on Warp vs the effort put into the Galaxy class book (which to be fair made some stuff way more technobabble then necessary).  I personally have not seen the warp 8 claim anywhere but I'm not claiming full knowledge.
